# Splitting js into multiple lines

Tags: javascript

On a web page I have for work, I have a google map with sites marked on it, along with labels containing contact information for that site. In dense areas like Boston or New York, I have multiple sites' contact info within a single label. The issue I'm having is that I can only get this to function correctly when I put all sites' contact info into a single text line like below.

```
var labelBoston = [
  new GInfoWindowTab("Center", "<b>Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center</b><br>Jon Doe, MD<br>Harvard Medical School<br>address line here<br>Boston, MA 02215<br>Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx<br>Fax: xxx-xxx-xxxx<br><a href='mailto:jondoe@BIDMC.com'>jondoe@BIDMC.com</a><br><br><b>Boston Medical Center</b><br>Jane Doe, Study Coordinator<br>Dept. of Obstetrics-Gynecology<br>address line here<br>100th Floor<br>Boston, MA 02118<br>Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx<br><a href='mailto:janedoe@BMC.com'>janedoe@BMC.com</a>"),
];
```

While this works, it's a huge pain to maintain. Especially in other cities where there are >5 sites to deal with. I would like to split this into something like:

```
var labelBoston = [
  new GInfoWindowTab("Center", "
<b>Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center</b><br>Jon Doe, MD<br>Harvard Medical School<br>address line here
<br>Boston, MA 02215<br>Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx<br>Fax: xxx-xxx-xxxx
<br><a href='mailto:jondoe@BIDMC.com'>jondoe@BIDMC.com</a>

<br><br>

<b>Boston Medical Center</b><br>Jane Doe, Study Coordinator
<br>Dept. of Obstetrics-Gynecology<br>address line here
<br>100th Floor<br>Boston, MA 02118<br>Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx
<br><a href='mailto:janedoe@BMC.com'>janedoe@BMC.com</a>"),
    ];
```

Or something similar so that maintaining this information is more managable. But any variation I make to the singular text line completely breaks everything. Can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: I would suggest breaking each line into strings, and then in the end just concatenate them to one huge string. For instance, the line `Harvard Medical School` could be `var school = 'Harvard Medical School <br />;`. This way it's easy to maintain different bits of your string by themselves.

Comment: I would suggest storing HTML in HTML files and then load them with ajax, rather than hard coding your HTML in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to escape the carriage return. i.e., just put a `\` right before you press enter. But there's 4 different ways I can think of.

```js
let a = `There's a few ways about multi-line strings in Javascript.
In ES6, template literals allow multiple lines,`

let b = "but you can also have multiple lines by \
escaping the carriage return,"

let c = "or by using " +
"String concatenation,"

let d = [
    "or you can join",
    "items in an array."
].join(" ")

console.log(a,b,c,d);
```

Comment: Using template literals includes the carriage return in the text itself; the others do not. Just a heads up to the OP and others.

Answer (score 0):

Split each line or couple lines into it's own string. For example,

```
"Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center
Jon Doe, MD
Harvard Medical School
address line here 
Boston, MA 02215
Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx
Fax: xxx-xxx-xxxx 
jondoe@BIDMC.com"
```

Could be,

```
var string = '';
string += 'Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center<br />';
string += 'Jon Doe, MD.<br />';
string += 'Harvard Medical School<br />';
string += 'address line here <br />';
string += 'Boston, MA 02215<br />';
string += 'Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx<br />';
string += 'Fax: xxx-xxx-xxxx <br />';
string += 'jondoe@BIDMC.com<br />';
```

Then at the end just concatenate your strings (`var total_string = string + string1 + string2 +...b`) and then say,

```
var labelBoston = [ 
  new GInfoWindowTab("Center", total_string);
];
```